# Android: adt was unable to instantiate class com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.editors.common.CommonXmlEditor

Tags: android

This problem appears to me when I try to open any xml file in eclipse:

> Plug-in "com.android.ide.eclipse.adt" was unable to instantiate class "com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.editors.common.CommonXmlEditor".

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Have you tried cleaning the project / restarting your computer?

Comment: Try updating ADT plugin in your eclipse, It might solve your problem!!!

Comment: Unfortunatly, the problem still exists.